# Locally bounded iff locally integrable derivative

Tags: integration, analysis

Suppose $f$ is a $C^1$ function. Is this function locally bounded if and only if its derivative $f'$ is locally integrable?

One direction of the proof goes as follows:

Let $K$ be a compact set, $f$ locally bounded so for any $x,y\in K$ it holds that  $f(x), f(y)$ are finite,so
\begin{equation}
\infty> f(x) - f(y) = \int_x^y f'(z)dz.
\end{equation}
Since $K$ was arbitrary, $f'$ is locally integrable.

I would say that the other direction follows from the above equality, but is it correct to say that $f(x) - f(y)<\infty$ implies finiteness of $f(x)$ because $f$ is $C^1$? This looks like some basic analysis but I am confused by whether we can have a continuous function attaining a value $+\infty$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any $C^1$ function is both locally integrable and locally bounded. This is almost trivial for all continuous functions.